# Want to check ip address format in apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

if url_chk_str matches any ip address similar to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx then do something.
here x denotes any integer value from 0 to 9
url_chk_str is any string in the input data.

For example :- 123.456.789.101

is the above scenario possible in apache pig? if yes how?

Let me know if someone wants any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
a = load '/path/data' using PigStorage() as (url_chk_str, somethingelse);
b = foreach a generate ((url_chk_str matches '[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]') ? value_if_true : value_if_false)
```